# Solving $2^n - 2\times n = a $, where $a$ is a known constant

Tags: exponentiation, real-numbers

Solving $2^n - 2\times n = a $, where $a$ is a known constant.

This is my first question.
I am having trouble solving the equation in the title...moreover I do not even know the name of that kind of equations. Any help would be veeeery appreciated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Lambert-W function is indeed the key term I needed to find  a direct way to solve it as I found here:  https://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function.html

Comment: You need to specify if $n$ is an integer or a real. That makes very different solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
2^n-2n=a
&\iff e^{\ln{(2)}n}=2n+a\\
&\iff 1=(2n+a)e^{-\ln{(2)}n}\\
&\iff -\frac{\ln{(2)}}2=\left(-\ln{(2)}n-\frac{\ln{(2)}a}2\right)e^{-\ln{(2)}n}\\
&\iff -\frac{\ln{(2)}}2e^{-\ln{(2)}a/2}=\left(-\ln{(2)}n-\frac{\ln{(2)}a}2\right)e^{-\ln{(2)}n-\ln{(2)}a/2}\\
&\iff W_k\left(-\frac{\ln{(2)}}2e^{-\ln{(2)}a/2}\right)=-\ln{(2)}n-\frac{\ln{(2)}a}2\\
&\iff n=-\frac{a}2-\frac1{\ln{(2)}}W_k\left(-\frac{\ln{(2)}}2e^{-\ln{(2)}a/2}\right)\\
&\iff n=-\frac{a}2-\frac1{\ln{(2)}}W_k\left(-\frac{\ln{(2)}}{2^{a/2+1}}\right)\\
\end{align}
Here $W_k(z)$ denotes the $k$th branch of the Lambert-W function.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I will study further this topic. Much appreciated :)

Comment: I do not know why I cannot upvote your answer as it is the most precise one...

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is a natural, we have the following sequence for $a$:

$$0,0,2,8,22,52,114,240,490,1004,\cdots$$

For higher $a$,

$$m=\lceil\log_2a\rceil$$ will give you a candidate solution and you can test

$$2^m-2m=a.$$

Comment: N is meant to be a Real number. Thanks for sharing your way to tackle the problem. I believe I could have also solved the equation for a given numeric value with the Newton-Raphson method but I wanted to learn something new.